# Do IP65-rated LED strips need a wet-rated channel enclosure too?

Tags: electrical, led, waterproofing, stairs

As I described in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/229237/is-is-safe-to-use-led-strips-that-shine-onto-stair-risers-instead-of-directly-on), I'm planning to mount 12V LED strips under the treads of an outdoor wood staircase. The [strips](https://www.prolighting.com/indoor-lighting/led-tape-light/49-299/di-12v-blx1-24-w100.html) I'm considering are rated [IP65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code#Second_digit:_Liquid_ingress_protection). Does the aluminum channel enclosure *also* need to be wet-rated?

I'm asking because I'd like to use a 16mm 45-degree channel like the one pictured below, and I believe that this channel is IP60, meaning "not water-resistant". I've seen 45-degree channels claiming "IP65 with the right sealant" but those channels are taller: at least 19mm. Even the 16mm enclosure is quite noticeable, so I'd like to I'd really like to avoid taller ones if possible.

[image]

The channel will be mounted upside down, so it won't be rained on directly nor will water be able to pool near the strip.  Here's a not-to-scale idea of the setup I'm planning to use:

[image]

Or is waterproofing these enclosures less about the enclosure geometry and really just about using the right sealant when attaching the diffuser and the end caps?

Conversely, would it be *better* not to use sealant when attaching the diffuser so that any water that does get in there can drain out the bottom?  It's a really tight fit even without sealant, if that matters.

I've done a fair amount of DIY electrical work, but never outdoors or in wet environments so waterproofing is a bit of a mystery to me. Thanks for helping with my novice questions!

Comment: With waterproof strips I would go for making the channels drain easily so any water that does get in doesn't pool in there.